# Macro which points the cell represented by an array element

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 columns in a excel sheet .
first column has some other cell address for example - column A has contents F1, F2, F3, F4 and F5.
Second column also has some other cell address for example - column B has contents x1, X13, X17, X72.

Now I want macro which can copy the contents of cells mentioned in column first (want to copy contents of F1 ...F5) to cells mentioned in the column 2.

Please help

Comment: I will say you could do it by copying the text from those cells and then using that text in the `Range()` object in VBA, but the most important question is what have you tried so far??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Adding detail to your question will get you better answers.  For instance, do the contents of Column A contain the word 'and' or is it a comma-separated list of Cell Addresses?  What should happen if Range A isn't the same size as Range B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each cell in column A only contains a single cell address:

```
Sub TransferValues()

Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range
Dim srcAddress As Range
Dim destAddress As Range
Dim r As Long   'row iterator

Set rngA = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set rngB = rngA.Offset(0, 1)

For r = 1 To rngA.Rows.Count
    Set srcAddress = Range(rngA(r).Value)
    Set destAddress = Range(rngB(r).Value)
    destAddress.Value = srcAddress.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi David .. Thanks for your help.    Based on your help I am able to content of cell in column 2 of workbook 1 to another workbook. the code is :Sub TransferValues()

Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range
Dim srcAddress As Range
Dim destAddress As Range
Dim r As Long   'row iterator
VarW1 = "a.xlsx"
Sht1 = "Sheet1"
Set rngA = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set rngB = rngA.Offset(0, 1)

For r = 1 To rngA.Rows.Count
    Set srcAddress = Range(rngA(r).Value)
    Set destAddress = Workbooks(VarW1).Sheets(Sht1).Range(rngB(r).Value)
    destAddress.Value = srcAddress.Value
Next

End Sub

Comment: You're welcome! If this has helped solve your problem, kindly "confirm" my suggested answer.